# How to take,delete,update data realtime from localStorage in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, local-storage

so i want to make a page that render a data from localStorage, i want to make it realtime, so if i wanti to delete some data from localStorage the UI of deleted data removed realtime

This is my code, but it does not realtime, i need to reload to look the changes

```
const [favoritesPkg, setFavoritesPkg] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    let a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedPkg"));
    setFavoritesPkg(a);
}, []);

const handleRemoveAll = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("savedPkg");
};

return (...)
```

I also try this code, i show what i expected but there is an error: maximum depth render

[image]

```
const [favoritesPkg, setFavoritesPkg] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    let a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedPkg"));
    setFavoritesPkg(a);
}, [favoritesPkg]);

const handleRemoveAll = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("savedPkg");
}
```

so in my component there is an action button like edit, and delete...i want if i delete single component from data in localStorage will disappear realtime, so i do not need refresh my page to see that changes

Comment: try this : useEffect(() => {
if(favoritesPkg == null  || favoritesPkg .length == 0) {
    let a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedPkg"));
    setFavoritesPkg(a);}
}, []);

Answer (score 1):

For fixing this you need to update handleRemoveAll function. In this function you are only removing the item from localstorage. You are not updating the state. Please update the function as follow.

```
const handleRemoveAll = () => {
localStorage.removeItem("savedPkg");
setFavoritesPkg(null);

}
```

And also update the useEffect to this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    
}, [favoritesPkg]);
```

This will surely update the UI in realtime.

Comment: If he updates the useEffect to be what you mentioned, he will not load the data at first render.

Comment: @Ogrodev but if he keep the dependency blank then Ui will not be re render. So there should be two useEffect one for first time render and other for tracking changes

Comment: @fyz-08 is this helpful?

Comment: nope, the useEffect does not trigger a re-render by itself.
Look at the sample code I wrote and the explanation of it

Comment: ohh thanks @Ogrodev for handleRemoveAll function, i forget to reset the useState, it was helpfull....but i am still stuck for useeffect depedency, it added [favoritesPkg] as depedency but there is an error like a mention before "warning: maximum depth update"

Comment: thanks too for @Riya meghnani it was helpfulll for handleRemoveAll

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand one thing: React only rerenders when you update a stateful variable.

Stateful variables are those created with useState, useReducer or an external library such as Redux, Jotai, Mobx, etc...

Second thing is, if you have a useEffect where you update a variable and you look for the variable inside the dependency array, you will end up in a loop.

So NEVER do something like you are doing in your seconde code example

To achieve the result, you want change your code adding a `setFavoritesPkg` inside the `handleRemoveAll` function.

Your code should look like this:

```js
const [favoritesPkg, setFavoritesPkg] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
/* Notice the addition of a conditional to check for the localStorage item,
if you don't do that, you can end up crashing your application when trying the
JSON.parse() */
    const storedPackages = localStorage.getItem("savedPkg")
    if(storedPackages){
      let a = JSON.parse();
      setFavoritesPkg(a);      
    }
}, []); // removed favoritesPkg from the dependency array so you don't fall into an eternal loop

const handleRemoveAll = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("savedPkg");
    setFavoritesPkg([]) // reseting favoritesPkg to empty array
}
```

If you want to update something in the screen (trigger a re-render) update the state variable, localStorage is not observed by react to update the dom.

Comment: I use redux, this is my action ` reducers: {
    saveToLocalStorage: (state, action) => {
      state.packages.unshift({
        ...
      });
      localStorage.setItem("savedPkg", JSON.stringify(state.packages));
    },

    deleteFromLocalStorage: (state, action) => {
      const id  = action.payload;
      const newPkg = state.packages.filter(x => x.id != id)
      localStorage.setItem('savedPkg', JSON.stringify(newPkg))

    },
  },`

Comment: so in my question before, i take the data from localStorage...should i take the data using useSelector? is it better for my probelm??